# Use AsyncIterator in Typescript – required options

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, async-iterator

Consider this basic [AsyncIterator Example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Iterating_over_async_iterables):

```
var asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      i: 0,
      next() {
        if (this.i < 3) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: this.i++, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};

(async function() {
   for await (let num of asyncIterable) {
     console.log(num);
   }
})();
```

Running this on node 10.16.0 works fine. However, I cannot seem to make it run via Typescript. Using this tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2016", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "target": "es2016"
  }
}
```

results in error `The type returned by the 'next()' method of an async iterator must be a promise for a type with a 'value' property.` Same error for target `esnext`.

If I remove the `target` option entirely, I get a `Type '{ [Symbol.asyncIterator](): { i: number; next(): Promise<{ done: boolean; }>; }; }' is not an array type or a string type.`

The [TS manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#the-for-await-of-statement) mentions several caveats, none of which could solve my problem. Oddly enough, [iterating async generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#Iterating_over_async_generators) works fine.

Which tsconfig options are required to make this example compile?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: Well, `{ done: true }` doesn't have a  `.value` property.

Comment: @Bergi right but it shouldn't have to, at least it isn't required by the ECMAScript specification... I wish that object had been defined with `type IteratorResult<T> = {
  value: T;
  done: boolean;
} | {
  value?: undefined;
  done: true;
}`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think it's a good practice to always return objects of the same shape nonetheless.

Comment: @Bergi would you count `{ value: undefined, done: true }` the same shape as `{ value: i++, done: false }`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, the properties are the same, even if unfortunately the types are not.

Comment: I don't see how that's unfortunate... for loops don't even iterate the result with `done: true` so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After digging a little further into the problem, it appears it is due to multiple issues here.

The async iterator can't rely on its context (e.g. `this.i`) to access properties that are not part of the `AsyncIterator` interface. Doing so will not compile in the current version of TypeScript 3.6 (even if it works fine in JavaScript), so to work around that we are left with:

```
var asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let i = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        if (i < 3) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: i++, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Now the problem appears to be related to `value` missing in the second return statement. Because the `IteratorResult` interface is defined like this:

```
interface IteratorResult<T> {
  done: boolean;
  value: T;
}
```

the `next()` method must *always* return an object with `value: number` (again, even if it works fine in JavaScript), so finally we have:

```
var asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    let i = 0;
    return {
      next() {
        if (i < 3) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: i++, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ value: i, done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};
```